# Could Mapserver's Internal Server Error be caused by msEvalRegex?

Tags: mapserver, linux

I try Mapserver 5.6.4 on Linux.

I've compiled Mapserver ,then put it on /cgi-bin/ direcotry.
I tried to access "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv",
but "500: Internal Server Error" was shown.

I saw error point, and I guessed that msEvalRegex() didn't work.
So I commented out mapfile.c codes of between 5190 lines and 5202 lines.
(  if(getenv("MS_MAPFILE_PATTERN")....)

Then, mapserver worked well.
(I got a response "200")
I don't know the reason. (Mapserver needs any other library??)
Please tell me about it.

My english is very poor, sorry.

Comment: Try first with a newer version v. 7.0 or at least 6.4.

Comment: I tried version 6.4.3. The same problem occuered.

Answer (score 1):

The mapserv binary created needs to have `—rwxr-xr-x` permissions to be able to execute so if needed you can change permissions using:

```
#chmod 755 mapserv
```

To test you have compiled mapserv with all appropriate options you can check the version:

```
#./mapserv —v
```

you should get an output like:

```
MapServer version 5.6.4 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=WBMP OUTPUT=PDF OUTPUT=SVG SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS SUPPORTS=RGBA_PNG INPUT=EPPL7 INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

If you get an output like this, then you know that MapServer is compiled correctly for your system; then you can move on to configuring the web service.

Comment: The mapserver I complied showed one's version like what you said. And that is the same on 6.4.3 version.

Comment: Apache's log showed "*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast):" This infomation help to find problems?